# How to set a timer to go to the next item in the list?

Tags: jquery, timer

I would like to make it so that after every 5 seconds the next slide will appear automatically. Also I want to make it so that clicking next/prev will reset the timer. How do I achieve this? So far I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/5yL8a1av/4/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".divs > div").each(function (e) {
    if (e != 0) $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function () {
    if ($(".divs > div:visible").next().length != 0) {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(1000)
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(".divs > div:first").fadeIn(1000);
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
    if ($(".divs > div:visible").prev().length != 0) {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn(1000);            
        });
    } else {
        $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(".divs > div:last").fadeIn(1000);
        });

    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of clearTimer and global variables

Set a global variable to store your timer, and when the page loads or when next/prev are activated, set the timer again. You could wrap the setTimeout command into a function and call that instead as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var autoTimer;

    // set auto timer
    autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        goNext();
    }, 5000);

    $(".divs > div").each(function (e) {
        if (e != 0) $(this).hide();
    });

    function goNext() {
        if ($(".divs > div:visible").next().length != 0) {
            $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(1000)
            });
        } else {
            $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(".divs > div:first").fadeIn(1000);
            });
        }
        // clear timer
        clearTimeout(autoTimer);

        // set auto timer
        autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            goNext();
        }, 5000);
        return false;
    }

    $("#next").click(function () {
        return goNext();
    });

    $("#prev").click(function () {
        if ($(".divs > div:visible").prev().length != 0) {
            $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $(this).prev().fadeIn(1000);            
            });
        } else {
            $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(".divs > div:last").fadeIn(1000);
            });

        }

         // clear timer
        clearTimeout(autoTimer);

        // set auto timer
        autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            goNext();
        }, 5000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how this can be done:

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0tLxkdpm/)

```js
var showNext = function() {
  if ($(".divs > div:visible").next().length != 0) {
    $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).next().fadeIn(1000)
    });
  } else {
    $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(".divs > div:first").fadeIn(1000);
    });
  }
};
var showPrev = function() {
  if ($(".divs > div:visible").prev().length != 0) {
    $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).prev().fadeIn(1000);
    });
  } else {
    $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(".divs > div:last").fadeIn(1000);
    });

  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".divs > div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0) $(this).hide();
  });

  $("#next").click(function() {
    showNext();
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    showPrev();
    return false;
  });

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    showNext();
  }, 1000);
  $('#next, #prev').one('click', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});
```

```css
#one {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#two {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#three {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#prev {
  background: gray;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
#next {
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs">
  <div id="one">
    <div class="content-b">
      <h1>KEYS TO SUCCESS</h1>

      <h3>Digial Design Intern</h3>
      <a href="#">
        <div id="c">LEARN MORE</div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <div class="content-b">
      <h1>KEYS TO FAILURE</h1>

      <h3>Digial Design Intern</h3>
      <a href="#">
        <div id="c">LEARN LESS</div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="three">
    <div class="content-b">
      <h1>KEYS TO FAILURE</h1>

      <h3>Digial Design Intern</h3>
      <a href="#">
        <div id="c">LEARN LESS</div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="prev">Prev</div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your next button code in a recursive setTimeout function.

```
(function loopsiloop(){
       setTimeout(function(){        
      if ($(".divs > div:visible").next().length != 0) {
            $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(1000)
            });
        } else {
            $(".divs > div:visible").fadeOut(1000, function () {
                $(".divs > div:first").fadeIn(1000);
            });
        }
           loopsiloop();      
       }, 5000);
    })();
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yL8a1av/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try bx slider?..Here is a link http://bxslider.com/